# How can I specify a Default value dynamically in Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, annotations, jersey

I am using Java Jersey library to create RESTful web service.

I am using query param for method. I want to specify the Default value for that query param. If I specify a constant string, then it is fine. But how can I specify a runtime value as the default value?

```
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

@Path( "Hello" ) 
public class HelloWorld 
{ 
    private String defaultValue = "Default"; 

    @GET 
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ) 
    public String greet( @QueryParam( "User" ) @DefaultValue( "defaultValue" )String userName ) 
    { 
        String returnValue = "Hello " + userName; 
        System.out.println( returnValue ); 
        return returnValue; 
    } 
}
```

Instead of a constant how can I use a variable here? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible - at least not using the annotation. Can you say more about why you need to do that? Maybe I can then suggest some alternative approach.

Comment: I can think of a case where a date needs to be ther in a query param and should be defaulted to today

Comment: This is my use-case

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but did you tried to make the default value final?

```
final String defaultValue = "Default";
```

It works for me.